# Detect if a click was made in child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `window.open` to open a new window in javascript and I want to detect clicks made in child window. Suppose if a click was made in the child window I want to make some changes in the parent window. I'm already storing the handle of the child window like `var child = window.open()`. I have some code like `child.onclick = function()` in my parent window but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When you write just `window.open()`, does anything happen? - Does your child window open?

Answer (score 1):

I would execute the code from the child window as follows:

```
window.onclick = window.opener.someFunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var window = new Window();
var child = window.open();

var childFlag = false;
var onclick = new function() {
    alert ('hello');
    flag = true;
}

child.addEventListener('click', onclick);

var parentClick = function() {
    if(childFlag) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

You would create your parent and child windows as normal. Then when a click occurs within the child window, you'd mark off a flag, that the parent also has access to, to indicate that a click occurred. And then do something within the parent window based on that.

Answer (score 1):

@kcollins02 has a good answer. If the communication is one-way from the child to the parent. If the communication has to go both ways, I would recommend using jquery events as described in this article: http://www.manasinc.com/communicating-between-two-browser-windows-using-jquery-and-custom-events/